# I can't get the posted values in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony2 and Doctrine 2.

I created a form in Symfony2. But I am not able to get the posted values in the controller. The syntax I use to get the values is:

```
$block = $request->request->get('txtblock');
```

Comment: The code to get POSTed values is correct. So most likely the name of the value is incorrect or wasn't submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use a `var_dump()` on `$request->request->all()`. That way, you can debug what has been send. Most likely, your form/input field has a different name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to print the content of $_POST. It's not the way Symfony is designed to be, but if $_POST is empty too, I guess the problem is on your form submission.